Solving Laplace equation on a disk
I have been given the Dirichlet problem for the unit disk:
$$\Delta u=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r } \left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)+\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial \theta^2}=0$$
with boundary condition:$$u(1,θ) = 2\cos(2\theta) − 4\sin(9\theta)$$
So far I have used separation of variables by $v(r,\theta) = S(\theta) \cdot R(r)$ to obtain ODE's: $$S''(\theta) = -\lambda S(\theta),$$ $$r^2R''(r) + rR'(r) = \lambda R(r)$$
With general solutions being:
$$S(\theta) = C_1 e^{i\sqrt\lambda\theta} + C_2 e^{-i\sqrt\lambda\theta}$$
$$R(r) = c_1 r^{\sqrt\lambda} + c_2r^{-\sqrt\lambda}$$
Could anyone help me with how to acquire a solution satisfying the boundary condition from this?? Thanks in advance!

Define $h(\theta):=u(1,\theta)$ and use the Poisson Kernel
$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{PK}(r,\phi-\theta)h(\phi)\mathrm d\phi$$
Where $$\operatorname{PK}(r,\theta):=\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}$$ is the (two dimensional) Poisson Kernel.

You are almost there. First, you can rewrite $S(\theta)$ in terms of sine and cosine functions: $$S(\theta)=\alpha\sin(\sqrt\lambda\theta)+\beta\cos(\sqrt\lambda\theta)$$
Then your solution is a superposition of $S_\lambda(\theta)R_\lambda(r)$, so you can write it as $$u(r,\theta)=\sum_\lambda S_\lambda(\theta)R_\lambda(r)$$
You just need to keep the correct values for $\lambda$ in the sum. So from your boundary conditions, you need to keep $\sqrt\lambda=2$ and $\sqrt\lambda=9$.
If you plug in these values and identify the coefficients of sine and cosine terms, you should get
$$u(r,\theta)=\left(c_1r^2+(2-c_1)r^{-2}\right)\cos(2\theta)+\left(c_2r^9-(4+c_2)r^{-9}\right)\sin(9\theta)$$
Depending where your function is $0$ (at $0$ or at $\infty$), you can also find the values for $c_1$ and $c_2$.
